# ubuntu keeps deleting my startup applications

Tags: startup-applications

I need some help tracking this one down.  I set guake to launch at startup or better yet login.  I've set it a bunch of times but it just keeps being deleted.  Sometimes I can reboot and it launches just fine, but more often then not it doesn't.  The entry is gone in the startup applications app.  I've set it to come on in gnome tweaks and that doesn't seem to work either.  What can I do to fix this, it's super annoying.

Edit It is being deleted at start up. So if I add it it's there for the next start but after that it's gone.  I've been watching the ~.config/autostart directory and when guake.desktop is there it starts on the next boot, but when I look in the folder guake.desktop is gone.  What would be deleting that entry on boot?

Comment: Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting

Answer (score -1):

It was guake deleting the file when it launched.  there is setting in guake to start the applications at start up.